# Mutually recursive methods with defaults

Tags: perl, oop

Lets say I've got a class with the following methods (this is a bit silly, I know, in reality it's got more to do with default directories):

```
sub getOne { my $self = shift; return $self->getZero() + 1; }
sub getZero { my $self = shift; return $self->getOne() - 1; }
```

I want to allow the user to override either one, both or none of these methods. In the case of overriding one of the methods, the other one of course takes the default, so setting `getOne` to `7` would result in `getZero` being `6`. The user can also override both. But also the user can override none at all, in which case the results should be the obvious `1` and `0`. This is the case where the above code fails, it enters a infinite loop in this case.

I know I could have:

```
sub getOneOverride { undef; }
sub getZeroOverride { undef; }

sub getOne  
{ 
  my $self = shift; 
  return $self->getOneOverride() or 
    ($self->getZeroOverride() ? $self->getZeroOverride() + 1 : 1); 
}

sub getZero 
{
  my $self = shift; 
  return $self->getZeroOverride() or 
    ($self->getOneOverride() ? $self->getOneOverride() - 1 : 0); 
}
```

But this would require separate override and reading methods, which I find a bit messy.

Any way to achieve the above without separate "override" methods?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here, I've just solved this by breaking the loop with an optional parameter, i.e.

```
sub getOne  { my $self = shift; return $self->getZero(1) + 1; }

sub getZero 
{
  my ($self, $default_call) = @_;
  return $default_call ? 0 : $self->getOne() - 1;  
}
```